# Can't "make" lib-tins on Ubuntu 16

Tags: built-in

I've downloaded the tins tar.gz file, proceeded to Cmake with c++ flags but couldn't accomplish "make".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I've downloaded the tar.gz to wrong path.
Fix: copy tar.gz to /home or etc.